# Any book/article that talks about a difference in what science achieves and what society wants/needs?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request

I'm not trying to ignite a discussion on the topic, simply a reading reference for someone who talks about any difference between the academia and society - for example I've seen a book (published last year) called "Another Science is Possible" by Isabelle Stengers (haven't read it yet, but it's on my reading list) which is suppose to talk about slowing down science in order for society to keep up with it. So, anything on this line of thought would be nice.

Comment: Nicholas Maxwell, 1984, From Knowledge to Wisdom: A Revolution in the Aims and Methods of Science, Basil Blackwell, Oxford.  He has a Wikipedia too. This is in the general area of what you are asking.

Comment: Mildly related, you might be interested in my recent blog posts on [if/how scientists can learn to listen to society](https://egtheory.wordpress.com/2018/07/07/listening/).

Comment: Silent Spring fits. Jordan Peterson I think argues that ethics need to consciously determine the direction we take science in, that scientific truth is nested within larger ethical truths aound our survival and flourishing.